# WCF service with username security should accept messages with additional ws-security headers. Is it possible?

Tags: wcf, ws-security, xml-dsig

I have an wcf service that has classical username-password message security.
On transport level this service has https

Binding is typical

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RgiServiceBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

But. Now we should add client signing to this interchange. We decide to use standard wsse headers for this signature.
Example:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IRgiService/RegisterAuction</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:054cd820-1e0c-4643-881d-48d8c7682080</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://ws.test.rosim.ru:8443/RGI_ETP/RgiService.svc</a:To>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken b:Id="urn:uuid:bc811ecb-4313-44f4-a627-9237d147294e" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:b="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <Username>login</Username>
        <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:actor="http://esugi.rosim.ru/pibi/actors/etp">
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr34102001-gostr3411" />
          <Reference URI="#body8d018149d5ea441a817ea018da2c8ce1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr3411" />
            <DigestValue>0pgHWuhnDlw/s8aHBxbk2FrHc072go1xXE/JnUBboRk=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>aL6ag12120eSmz6CQYQY8HjgZ+Gdz6UfaRZdV9qXY21ccxVfCkme1zsSw9Vy4jh2ofK/QYsebomEnWd51xIq1w==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#cert9c65aba5ea814fc5a27137859c9c3df2" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="cert9c65aba5ea814fc5a27137859c9c3df2">therewascertificateinbase64</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <RegisterAuction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" wsu:Id="body8d018149d5ea441a817ea018da2c8ce1">
      <auctionInfo xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Rgi.Etp.Service.Contract.DataContracts">
        <b:AuctionNumber>1112233</b:AuctionNumber>
        <b:Note>Новый аукцион создан</b:Note>
      </auctionInfo>
      <tradeRequestInfo xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Rgi.Etp.Service.Contract.DataContracts">
        <b:TradeRequestDate>2015-03-11T00:00:00</b:TradeRequestDate>
        <b:TradeRequestNumber>111</b:TradeRequestNumber>
      </tradeRequestInfo>
    </RegisterAuction>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But WCF don't want to work with multiple wsse headers. It says "An error occurred when verifying security for the message." without any additional info, and it is before my own code.

**Can I do something to get my signatures on server side and my username validation works?**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "multiple WSSE headers"?  Or post an example?

Comment: I add example of xml